# Rvest unexpectedly stopped working - Scraping tables

Tags: r, rvest

After having used the following script for a while, it suddenly stopped working. I constructed a simple function that finds a table - based on its xpath - within a web page.

```
library(rvest)

url <- c('http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/floc.php/certificati/index/codice_ente/1010020010/cod/4/anno/1999/md/0/cod_modello/CCOU/tipo_modello/U/cod_quadro/08'

find_table <- function(x){read_html(x) %>%
                          html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="center"]/table[2]') %>%
                          html_table() %>%
                          as.data.frame()}

table <- find_table(url)
```

I also tried to use `httr::GET` before `read_html`, passing the following argument:

```
query = list(r_date = "2017-12-22")
```

but nothing changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that code doesn't work since you missed a `)` in the `url <-` line.

We'll add in `httr`:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
```

`url` is the name of a base function. using base function names as variables can make problems in code hard to debug. Unless you write perfect code, it's a good idea to not use the names that way.

```
URL <- c('http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/floc.php/certificati/index/codice_ente/1010020010/cod/4/anno/1999/md/0/cod_modello/CCOU/tipo_modello/U/cod_quadro/08')
```

I don't know if you know the "rules" about web scraping but if you're making repeated requests to this site, then a "crawl delay" should be used. They don't have one set in their robots.txt so 5 seconds is the accepted alternative. I point this out as you may be getting rate limited.

```
find_table <- function(x, crawl_delay=5) { 

  Sys.sleep(crawl_delay) # you can put this in a loop vs here if you aren't often doing repeat gets

  # switch to httr::GET so you can get web server interaction info.
  # since you're scraping, it's expected that you use a custom user agent
  # that also supplies contact info.

  res <- GET(x, user_agent("My scraper"))

  # check to see if there's a non HTTP 200 response which there may be
  # if you're getting rate-limited

  stop_for_status(res) 

  # now, try to do the parsing. It looks like you're trying to target a
  # single table, so i switched it from `html_nodes()` to `html_node()` since
  # the latter returns a `list` and the pipe will error out if there's more
  # than on list element.

  content(res, "parsed") %>% 
    html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="center"]/table[2]') %>%
    html_table() %>%
    as.data.frame()

}
```

`table` is a base function name, too (see above)

```
result <- find_table(URL)
```

Worked fine for me:

```
str(result)
## 'data.frame':  11 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ ENTI EROGATORI                          : chr  "Cassa DD.PP." "Istituti di previdenza amministrati dal Tesoro" "Istituto per il credito sportivo" "Aziende di credito" ...
##  $                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ ACCENSIONE ACCERTAMENTI                 : chr  "4.638.500,83" "0,00" "0,00" "953.898,47" ...
##  $ ACCENSIONE RISCOSSIONI C|COMP. + RESIDUI: chr  "2.177.330,12" "0,00" "129.114,22" "848.935,84" ...
##  $ RIMBORSO IMPEGNI                        : chr  "438.696,57" "975,07" "45.584,55" "182.897,01" ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I reapply appreciate you taking the time and going through this step by step. It's an enlightening answer.